# How to get object value array in common key

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 var obj= [{tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3405220}
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1108620}
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 9964980}
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3881360}
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 4090880}
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1657600}]
```

I want this object as output in below format

```
obj=[{tharea:"Rare Disease",value:[3405220,1108620,9964980,3881360,4090880,1657600]}]
```

I tried flatmap but i am not getting any expected result

Comment: So you want to group based on the tharea property?

Comment: yes want to to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce it

```js
var obj= [{tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3405220},
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1108620},
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 9964980},
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3881360},
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 4090880},
           {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1657600}]
           
let result = obj.reduce((a, { tharea, value }) => {
   let item = a.find(el => el.tharea === tharea)
   if (!item) return [...a, { tharea, value: [value] }];
   item.value.push(value);
   return a;
},[])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```js
var obj = [
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3405220},
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1108620},
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 9964980},
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3881360},
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 4090880},
  {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1657600}
];

var result = Object.values(obj.reduce((p, v) => {
  if (p[v.tharea])
    p[v.tharea].value.push(v.value);
  else
    p[v.tharea] = { ...v, value: [v.value] };
  return p;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var obj = [
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 3405220 },
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 1108620 },
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 9964980 },
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 3881360 },
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 4090880 },
  { tharea: 'Rare Disease', value: 1657600 },
];

const byTharea = obj.reduce((all, item) => {
  all[item.tharea] = all[item.tharea] || [];
  all[item.tharea].push(item.value);
  return all;
}, {});

const array = Object.keys(byTharea).map(tharea => ({
  tharea,
  values: byTharea[tharea],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Added explanation into the comments. reference [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function groupBy(obj) {
  // use reduce to loop over object and construct resultant object
  return obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // find if tharea value is already added
    let existing = acc.filter(x => x.tharea === item.tharea)[0];
    // if not added then push it to result (accumulator) object
    // else push value to existing object's value array
    if (!existing) {
      acc.push({
        tharea: item.tharea,
        value: [item.value]
      });
    } else {
      existing.value.push(item.value);
    }
    // return result object
    return acc;
  }, []); // use empty array as result object
}

var obj = [{
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 3405220
}, {
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 1108620
}, {
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 9964980
}, {
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 3881360
}, {
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 4090880
}, {
  tharea: "Rare Disease",
  value: 1657600
}];

// call groupBy function.
console.log(groupBy(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj= [{tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3405220},
       {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1108620},
       {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 9964980},
       {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 3881360},
       {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 4090880},
       {tharea: "Rare Disease", value: 1657600}];
let newObj = [];
obj.forEach((item) => {
  if (newObj.find(val => val.tharea === (item.tharea))) {
    for (let n of newObj) {
        if (n.tharea === item.tharea) {
            n.value.push(item.value);
        }
    }
  } else {
    newObj.push({"tharea": item.tharea, "value": [item.value]});
  }
});
console.log(newObj);
```